# CSV separates Date in two cells

Tags: powershell, csv

PowerShell program reads data from fixed Database in format Month Day, Year.

CSV outputs Month and Day in one cell, and Year in next cell.

How to fix this? I tried putting single and double-quotes around `$i[6]` and `$av_date`, and it still doesn't work

Code snippit

```
foreach ($i in $sql_output){
    $computer_name = $i[0]
    $ip = $i[1]
    $computer_domain = $i[2]
    $computer_os = $i[3]
    $current_group = $i[4]
    $sep_version = $i[5]
    $av_date = $i[6]
    Add-Content D:\Script\Reports\IP_Status_$date.csv "$computer_name,$ip,$computer_domain,$computer_os,$current_group,$sep_version,$av_date"
}
```

Output where entire date is not under Antivirus Date column

[image]

Comment: The problem must have to do with the `comma` after the "Day". Obviously, PowerShell has regarded that comma as a field SEPARATOR. What about using `Export-CSV`? That should work better.

Comment: You might succeed if you can escape the comma in your date string like so: `[regex]::Escape($av_date)`. Same for other relevant strings you wish to escape. Sorry, haven't tested!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inserting this on the line just before your `Add-Content` (note the triple quotes):

```
$av_date = """$av_date"""
```

Then go ahead:

```
Add-Content D:\Script\Reports\IP_Status_$date.csv "$computer_name,$ip,$computer_domain,$computer_os,$current_group,$sep_version,$av_date"
```

The comma in the date requires that the field is enclosed in quotes, and this is one way of achieving that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that whatever spreadsheet you are using (you don't mention it), that it ignores quotes and only looks for commas when parsing columns.

Generally putting something inside double quotes deals with this issue. Have you tried putting the quotes as shown below (\" quotes around av_date)?

```
Add-Content D:\Script\Reports\IP_Status_$date.csv "$computer_name,$ip,$computer_domain,$computer_os,$current_group,$sep_version,\"$av_date\""
```

Perhaps you could also try escaping the comma in the dates so that you'd have `Mar 05\, 2015` instead of the normal comma in there.

Either that, or change the format of your date to Mar-05-2015 or something similar that doesn't use commas.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't hack together functionality which PowerShell has built in. Just build an array of objects and use `Export-Csv` or `Export-Csv -Delimiter ';'` if that is required for your comma issue.

A quick example showing how to iterate over some input objects and building the output:

```
1..10 | foreach {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Index = $_
        String = "Just some text, with a comma $(3 * $_)"
        Date = (Get-Date).AddDays($_)
    }
} | Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This is a good approach. Would be a better answer if you show how to make an object that `Export-CSV` would expect